# Wpf custom DatePicker Calendar and CalendarDayButton

Tags: c#, wpf, button, datepicker, calendar

I'm customizing a DatePicker control in a WPF application, the target is to make it touchscreen-friendly.

I'm not familiar with WPF itself, but following few tutorials I've been able to make it bigger, I created a template for customizing the DatePicker itself and I added several controls in the code behind to restrict the date ranges and so on.

I'm just stuck when I try to change the "BlackoutDates" background:
[image: Calendar example]

Accordingly to the UX guidelines I have to change the "X" color from gray to red.

The datepicker itself looks good, the calendar doesn't:

```
<DatePicker Style="{StaticResource MyDatePickerStyle}" CalendarStyle="{StaticResource styleCalendar}" Height="60" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="datePicker1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="400">
    <DatePicker.BlackoutDates>
        <CalendarDateRange End="6/19/2019" />
        <CalendarDateRange Start="6/28/2019" />                    
    </DatePicker.BlackoutDates>                
</DatePicker>
```

and this is my template, the only effect I obtained is to make the calendar bigger:

```
<Style x:Key="styleCalendar" TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
    <Setter Property="CalendarDayButtonStyle" Value="{StaticResource
    styleCalendarButton}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
                <Viewbox Height="400" Width="400">
                    <CalendarItem x:Name="PART_CalendarItem"
                          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                          BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                          BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
                </Viewbox>
            </ControlTemplate>                    
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>        
</Style>

    <Style x:Key="styleCalendarButton" TargetType="CalendarDayButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type CalendarDayButton}}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsBlackedOut" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

I searched for several example, but it really seems I cannot customize the CalendarItem and its buttons easily.

**The question is: how can I change the "X" color on the background of blackout days?**

Comment: Are you setting the dates that are not red to a default value?  What is happening is the default value is a larger font so all the non red dates are growing larger making you calendar bigger.

Comment: Actually I have no problems related to calendar size, I just have no success to implement the red days.

Comment: You said : "the only effect I obtained is to make the calendar bigger".  First fix the problem with the calendar size by setting the other dates to black.

Comment: I don't have problems with calendar size: I exactly want to make it bigger, but I also need to make other tunings and the day button color is one I cannot achieve